# Installing systemtap 2.3 on ubuntu precise

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation

If I install systemtap using `apt-get` on ubuntu precise, I get systemtap 1.6.

Building it from source is proving to be complicated as it requires kernel headers.

Is there an easy way to install this?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty has the latest version. Any chance upgrading is an option? That's probably the easiest method.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I know it is there on ubuntu trusty. But cannot upgrade as the software that we are using needs to be upgraded too and that will take a lot of time. So now I have resigned myself to seeing if I can upgrade on 12.04 via packages on 14.04 as a test cases at least

Comment: Trying to install 14.04 packages on 12.04 will most likely not end well. I recommend you just compile it.

Answer (score 0):

Kernel headers are easy to install:  `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`